# Apache Rewrite Rule if 2 directories in url exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have been implementing a lot of redirect rules and I am stuck on the final one.  Some how a search engine has indexed some page which dont exist so I need to redirect them to the error page.

What I need to do is check if the url starts with the 2 directories /user/name/ and the other way /name/user/. If it does redirect to error page.

And example URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/user/name/12-how-do-we-work-together
```

I have tried the below Rule but doesnt seem to work:

```
RewriteRule ^user/name/?$ /error.php [R=301,L]
```

Any thoughts on this please?

Cheers

J

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `?$` in the rule fixed it for me.  Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/name/ /error.php [R=301,L]
```